# Stretch NSMenu/NSMenuitem to fit whole window

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I'm making a simple status bar app with AppKit, that displays NSMenu in the NSStatusBar.system.statusItem. So far so good but I'd like to make the very first NSItem having different color and act as a app/menu title. But the problem is, that I cannot stretch it to remove top margin. Now it looks like that:

[image: Menu example]

Is it possible to remove this top padding marked with green/yellow?

The code I use to load a view for this item:

```
class TitleView: NSView {
    func loadView() {
        var topLevelObjects: NSArray!
        let isNibLoaded = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
        if !isNibLoaded {
            print("Failed to load NIB from file")
        }
        let tv = (topLevelObjects.first(where: { $0 is NSView }) as? NSView)!
        self.addSubview(tv)
        
        tv.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(named: "MenuTitleColor")?.cgColor
        
        actionAbout = defaultAbout
    }
```

The code I use to set this view to the NSMenuItem:

```
var menuItemTitle: NSMenuItem!
var titleView: TitleView!
...
titleView = TitleView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 70))
        menuItemTitle.view = titleView
```

Thank you!